# Is `InverseMellinTransform` unaware of second Barnes lemma?

Tags: complex, integral-transforms

Consider evaluating

```
res = InverseMellinTransform[( Gamma[a + s] Gamma[b + s] Gamma[c + s] Gamma[1 - d - s] Gamma[-s])/ Gamma[a + b + c - d + 1 + s], s, 1] // FunctionExpand
```

> [image]

Even after the `FunctionExpand` the above returned hypergeometric functions instead of the expected gamma functions per [second Barnes Lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesLemma.html).

Numerically the result agrees

```
num = {a -> RandomComplex[WorkingPrecision -> 30], 
       b -> RandomComplex[WorkingPrecision -> 30], 
       c -> RandomComplex[WorkingPrecision -> 30], 
       d -> RandomComplex[WorkingPrecision -> 30]};
res - (Gamma[a] Gamma[b] Gamma[c] Gamma[1 - d + a] Gamma[ 1 - d + b] Gamma[1 - d + c])/( Gamma[e - a] Gamma[e - b] Gamma[e - c]) /. e -> a + b + c - d + 1 /. num
```

> `0.*10^-26 + 0.*10^-26 I`

Is this expected behavior? If yes, this would suggest that `InverseMellinTransform` might return an unnecessarily complicated output in other cases as well. Perhaps there is some way to extract the simpler gamma function result from `InverseMellinTransform` which I am not aware of?

Comment: My attitude is that *Mathematica* knows everything, and when it gives suboptimal results, it's just trolling you....  or at least that's how I feel.